# Python Dynamic Variable Calling

Tags: python, dynamic

I have the following little code:

```
         self.h2_demand.append(rand.randint(50, 100))
         self.o2_demand.append(rand.randint(50, 100))
```

How can I create a dynamic call of the self.variable? Something like:

```
     for i in range(1):  
         self. + variable_name[i] +.append()
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

Comment: I'm Note sure what your actual use-case is here, but storing them in a list or dictionary instead of "dynamic attributes" would probably make more sense.

Comment: If it's a specific amount like your example just do: `for lst in (self.h2, slef.o2)`. If it gets more complicated, change the design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Surfer101, you can use `getattr()`.

```
class A:
    h2 = list()
    o2 = list()
    def method(self):
        for i in 'h2', 'o2':
            getattr(self, i).append('some value')



instance = A()
instance.method()
instance.h2 # -> ['some value']
instance.o2 # -> ['some value']
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! Both answers helped me a lot! Regarding @Carcigenicate 's suggestion. I just want to have a list(key, value) with profiles I want to type in and configuring my objects based on that list. Let's see how this goes....:)

Answer (score 0):

@Surfer101,
You can instead use `getattr()`. Here is an example

```py
class Person:
    age = 23
    name = "John"

person = Person()

# when default value is provided
print('The sex is:', getattr(person, 'sex', 'Male'))

# when no default value is provided
print('The sex is:', getattr(person, 'sex'))
```